# Load assemblies with dependencies in a different AppDomain

Tags: c#, clr, appdomain, appdomainsetup

My aim is to make a missing dependency check between 2 given folders.
Imagine the following setup.

Root\DirA\A.dll

Root\DirB\B.dll

B depends on A.

So given these folders, I want to create a new AppDomain, load B.dll and have the dependency from DirA(A.dll) automatically resolved and isolated in that new AppDomain.

Isolation is key here given that when I unload this AppDomain I want to create a new one with potentially DirA as a dependency again but DirC libraries that require it so in the case that DirC has a dependency on DirB as well I want it to throw an exception.

Edit: Adding a code example in case that it helps describe my question better.

```
AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup();
setup.ApplicationBase = @"C:\Root";
setup.ApplicationName = "Isolated Domain"
setup.PrivateBinPath = @"DirA;DirB";
setup.PrivateBinPathProbe = "";//disable search in AppBase..
var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence,
                                    setup,
                                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.PermissionSet);
//The following statement in theory should pick B.dll's dependency from DirA.
var assembly = domain.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(@"C:\Root\DirB\B.dll").Name);
//Do the same in a different domain for C.dll
```

Thanks for any help on that.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a job for the [ResolveEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) (more detail on [MSDN regarding resolving unknown assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff527268.aspx))

So, you can write something like

```
class MyResolver
{
  public static Assembly MyResolveEventHandler( Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args )
  {
    // confirm args.Name contains A.dll
    String dllName = args.Name.Split({','}, SplitStringOptions.None)[0];
    if (dllName == "A")
    {
      return Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Root\DirA\A.dll")
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

and in the domain you created, you'd do a:

```
domain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(MyResolver.MyResolveEventHandler);
```

Make sure you bind the event before you reference A in B.

Comment: Yes I am aware of the event, couldn't get an implementation which uses it to work though :(

Comment: Thanks man, I ll let you know if it works once i get a chance to try it.

Comment: Adding a comment for future searchers - the AssemblyResolve event must be handled on the *parent* AppDomain, not the child AppDomain. The child AppDomain will fire the event on the parent AppDomain when an error occurs resolving the assembly.

Comment: just for other future-searchers: I had to add the resolvehandler to my newly created Domain and not on the Parent Appdomain.. ;)

Comment: If you set setup.DisallowApplicationBaseProbing = true; newly created Domain gets the AssemblyResolve event, otherwise the parent Domain gets it

Answer (score 1):

AppDomain's cannot probe for dll's outside of their initial folder.  They can probe in the GAC, and in the PrivateBinPath deeper into the folder, but they cannot probe into other folders.

Comment: The idea will be that the AppDomain's Base path will be the Root folder in the above example.